# Generic Generics or Type argument inference and inheritance

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to do something with Generics in .Net 4.5 C# and honestly, I'm not sure if it is possible or what it's called. Which makes searching that much more difficult.

Anyways, best to explain with an example.

Let's say I have some interface:

```
public interface ISomeBase {}
```

and an example of its implementation

```
public class AnObject : ISomeBase {}

public class AnOtherObject : ISomeBase {}
```

Then I've got ClassA which has a few generic methods like so

```
public class ClassA
{
    public T SomeMethod1<T>() where T : class, ISomeBase
    {
        //Do some stuff and return some T
        return default(T);
    }

    public List<T> SomeMethod2<T>(Expression<Func<T,object>> someExpression ) where T : class, ISomeBase
    {
        //Do some stuff and return some List<T>
        return new List<T>();
    }
```

}

I want to be able to use it like this (which I easily can):

```
public class SomeImplementation
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var obj = new ClassA();
        var v = obj.SomeMethod1<AnObject>();
        var v2 = obj.SomeMethod2<AnOtherObject>((t) => t.ToString());
    }
}
```

But I also want to be able to use it like this (this won't work as is due to type argument required. I understand that T in ClassB is different from T in every method in Class A:

```
public class ClassB<T> : ClassA where T: ISomeBase
{
    public T Tester()
    {
       //This is not possible and requires me to add a Type argument. 

        return SomeMethod1(); //I would like to leave out the type argument and have the compiler infer what it is

        // Some of the time I want to be able to apply the same type to all methods on ClassA. 
        // And some of the time I want to be able to specify the type arguments on a per method basis
    }
}
```

I want to avoid having to wrap ClassA into something like this:

```
public class ClassA<T> : ClassA where T : class, ISomeBase
{
    public T SomeMethod1()
    {
        return SomeMethod1<T>();
    }

    public List<T> SomeMethod2(Expression<Func<T, object>> someExpression)
    {
        return SomeMethod2<T>(someExpression);
    }
}
```

I've been searching and reading up on anything that I can get my hands on. But nothing seems to fit. Perhaps I'm not searching using the right terminology because, honestly, I don't know what it's called.

Any help or pointers will be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with `SomeMethod1<T>()` in `Tester` except that you need to add the `class` constraint to the constraints on `T`. C# doesn't, in general, look at the surrounding context to try and figure out what you meant and generic type inference specifically only operates on the information in the arguments, not the available generic type arguments in the surrounding call context.

Comment: Thanks mike z. There is nothing wrong with doing what you say. Due to the quantity of methods inside Class A, I thought it would be nice if there was a method of having the compiler being able to infer in both scenarios. But I'm not sure how to do that or if it's even possible. Perhaps my class structure is wrong, I don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving the compiler enough information for it to *infer* the type argument it should use.

**Type inference** is a very complex process to go through but, In general if a method type parameter doesn't appear in the *parameter list* then no type inference is performed for that *type parameter*. You might want to read the *C# spec*. to understand the details of type inference.

Hopefully someone can further clarify it.

Comment: Hi chomba. Thanks for the feedback. I understand about type inference and type inheritance. Perhaps my implementation of ClassA is incorrect and needs to be done differently in order to achieve what I want to. I'll take a look at the C# spec to see if there is anything I can find that will help. Thanks again.